# Wine32 dependencies problem

Tags: debian, wine

Since yesterday I tried to install Wine, everything was OK until I was asked to install wine32. The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
     wine32:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.7-2) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And it goes on... (libc6:i386)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dictionaries-common : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                                debconf-2.0
                       Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

and goes on...(libwine:i386)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libncurses5:i386 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                         libglu1:i386
                Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpcap0.8:i386 (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                         libopencl1:i386
                Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                         libopencl-1.1-1:i386
                Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                            libgl1:i386
                Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgsm1:i386 (>= 1.0.13) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libjpeg62-turbo:i386 (>= 1.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libodbc1:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 (>= 10.2~) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libpng16-16:i386 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 (> 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

None of the above can be installed.

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Of course I also tried everything people posted on the Internet,
`sudo apt-get upgrade -f`, `update`, `autoremove`, allowing i386 architecture, changing repository list etc.

Can someone grab my hand and help me go through this? Or maybe my system is beyond saving and I need to reinstall it?

@Edit

```
libc6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.24-11+deb9u3
  Version table:
     2.24-11+deb9u3 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
     2.24-11+deb9u1 990
        990 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages
```

Ok, I'm not sure but I guess it's not installed. How should I do that?

Comment: What does `apt policy libc6:i386` display? (Please [edit] your question to add this information.)